# How to take input from Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a program using Tkinter where the user inputs their weight in Pound and then it outputs their weight in kilo.

I'm having problems getting the contents of the `Entry` from the user.
I'm calculating the pound to kilo in `clicked1`.

Can someone show me how I would get the Entry input there?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Question 7")
        self.label = Label (self.root, text= "Enter your weight in pounds.")
        self.label.pack()

        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.entrytext).pack()

        self.buttontext = StringVar()
        self.buttontext.set("Calculate")
        Button(self.root, textvariable=self.buttontext, command=self.clicked1).pack()

        self.label = Label (self.root, text="")
        self.label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def clicked1(self):
        input = 3423 #I would like the user input here.
        self.label.configure(text=input)

    def button_click(self, e):
        pass

App()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have associated a `StringVar` with your `Entry` widget, you can easily access/manipulate the widget's text with StringVar's get and set methods.

See [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) for more information.

Answer (score 5):

Is this the kinda thing you are looking for?

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkMessageBox

class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Question 7")
        self.label = Label (self.root, text= "Enter your weight in pounds.")
        self.label.pack()


        self.entrytext = StringVar()
        Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.entrytext).pack()

        self.buttontext = StringVar()
        self.buttontext.set("Calculate")
        Button(self.root, textvariable=self.buttontext, command=self.clicked1).pack()

        self.label = Label (self.root, text="")
        self.label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()


    def clicked1(self):
        input = self.entrytext.get()
        result = int(input)*2
        self.label.configure(text=result)

    def button_click(self, e):
        pass

App()
```

I think this is what your'e looking for, although not just times by 2.
You would probably also want to put in an exception for if the value is not a int.

Answer (score 5):

What you are looking for is `[widget].get()`

### Text widget

In case you use the Text widget, you have to use `[widget].get(1.0, END)` where `1.0` means "first line, 0th character"

### Code review

I've noticed a few other things in your code that could get improved:

- [PEP8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conformity; see [pep8online.com](http://pep8online.com/)
- If you add a [Shebang](http://martin-thoma.com/what-does-usrbinpython-mean/), Linux users will be able to execute it directly with `./script.py`.
- Variable naming:

  - [`input`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#input) is a built-in function and you should avoid overwriting it
  - Use meaningful variable names (entrytext might be problematic in case you extend your program)
- Avoid `from Tkinter import *`. This might lead to unexpected naming clashes.

### Complete code

```
##!/usr/bin/env python

import Tkinter as Tk


class App(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk.Tk()
        self.root.wm_title("Question 7")
        self.label = Tk.Label(self.root, text="Enter your weight in pounds.")
        self.label.pack()

        self.weight_in_kg = Tk.StringVar()
        Tk.Entry(self.root, textvariable=self.weight_in_kg).pack()

        self.buttontext = Tk.StringVar()
        self.buttontext.set("Calculate")
        Tk.Button(self.root,
                  textvariable=self.buttontext,
                  command=self.clicked1).pack()

        self.label = Tk.Label(self.root, text="")
        self.label.pack()

        self.root.mainloop()

    def clicked1(self):
        weight_in_kg = self.weight_in_kg.get()
        self.label.configure(text=weight_in_kg)

    def button_click(self, e):
        pass

App()
```