# Having trouble running Python interpreter as a subprocess using Python's subprocess module

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess

I'm trying to understand how Python's subprocess module works and have begun by setting myself some problems that weren't as simple as I thought. Specifically, I'm trying to interact with a Python intepreter that has been created as a subprocess.

I've created a test module, `dummy.py` that is structured as follows:

```
def hi():
    print "Hi Earth"


hi()
```

Then, to test my ability to use the subprocess module, I've written a module called `pyrun.py`, that is structured as follows:

```
import subprocess

def subprocess_cmd1():
    outFile = open("tempy1.tmp",'w')
    proc = subprocess.Popen("pwd", stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile, shell=True)
    outFile.close()

def subprocess_cmd2():
    outFile = open("tempy2.tmp",'w')
    proc = subprocess.Popen('python dummy.py', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile, shell=True)
    outFile.close()

def subprocess_cmd3():
    outFile = open("tempy3.tmp",'w')
    proc = subprocess.Popen('python', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile, shell=True)
    proc.communicate('import dummy')
    outFile.close()

def subprocess_cmd4():
    outFile = open("tempy4.tmp",'w')
    proc = subprocess.Popen('python', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile, shell=True)
    proc.communicate('import dummy')
    proc.communicate('dummy.hi()')
    outFile.close()

print "Start"
subprocess_cmd1()
subprocess_cmd2()
subprocess_cmd3()
subprocess_cmd4()
print "Stop"
```

The idea is to send input to the subprocess from the calling process and to have all output sent to a text file.

When I attempt to run pyrun from the command line, I get the following results:

```
me@Bedrock1:~/Projects/LushProjects/newCode$ python pyrun.py
Start
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pyrun.py", line 42, in <module>
    subprocess_cmd4()
  File "pyrun.py", line 35, in subprocess_cmd4
    proc.communicate('dummy.hi()')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 785, in communicate
    self.stdin.write(input)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file
```

`subprocess_cmd1 - 3` run without crashing. The error comes in `subprocess_cmd4()`, when trying to execute the statement:

```
proc.communicate('dummy.hi()')
```

This seems to be because the `communicate` method closes the pipe to `stdin` after it's first used. Why does it do that? Is there any advantage to assuming the pipe should close?

Also, when I look at the contents of `tempy3.tmp` (my output file for `subprocess_cmd3`), it's missing the 'start' text of the Python interpreter - i.e.

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

Why is that? I redirected *both* `stdout` & `stderr` to `outFile`.

Finally, why is `tempy4.tmp` completely empty? Shouldn't it contain, at least, the text that was sent to it before it crashed? (i.e. it should look a lot like `tempy3.tmp`)

Comment: unrelated: why do you use subprocess to run Python code?

Comment: @J.F.Sebastien - I am really just experimenting with subprocess, to see if I understood how to use it & how it worked. I suppose a more realistic example would be using it to run code in an interpreter for some other language.

Comment: if it is a learning exersice then here're some hints: 1. avoid `shell=True`, use a list argument to pass the command 2. Know that a child process may behave differently if its stdin/stdout/stderr are redirected (e.g., to suppress color (ansi codes) in the output) or no header as in `python`'s case.

Comment: 3. Understand buffering issues (here's [a simple case where the parent only reads child's output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20503671/4279)): there are several buffers before `p.stdin.write("import dummy\n")` data is seen by the child. 4. child process may [read/write directly to terminal](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20980965/4279). Given pp.3 and 4  (for dialog-based interaction) [`pexpect` can be more convienient](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20185353/4279). 5. [you don't need multiple threads or multiprocessing to run several subprocesses in parallel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23616229/4279)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is how you're using `subprocess.communicate()`, which expects a single string. From the docs

https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate.
>   The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child
>   process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

Try this:

```
def subprocess_cmd4():
    outFile = open("tempy4.tmp",'w')
    proc = subprocess.Popen('python', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile, shell=True)
    proc.communicate('import dummy\ndummy.hi()\n')
    outFile.close()
```

Comment: Thanks. I came across a different solution, where I just used proc.stdin.write('....\n') for each line I fed to the interpreter. But I'm still wondering what's the advantage of having communicate close the pipe, and where did the 'intro' text from the Python interpreter go?

Comment: @user1245262: quote from the docs: *"Wait for process to terminate."* -- there is no point to call `communicate()` -- the child process is already dead. *"where did the 'intro' text from the Python interpreter go?"* -- python doesn't print it in non-interactive mode (if stdin is not connected to tty).

Comment: @user1245262: ^^^^^ "there is no point to call `communicate()`" **more than once**

Answer (score 4):

Define your interpreter:

```
interpreter=sys.executable
```

and pass a list as the first argument:

```
fproc=subprocess.Popen([interpreter,script,'-f',datafile], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Answer (score 0):

*Answering your question about `communicate()`.*

`communicate()` can only be used once, because the `outFile`  being called has been closed after the first communicate. Calling `communicate()` again will never produce anything because you have already read all the output in the previous one. An advantage of using this is that you do not need to terminate after you use it.

*Answering your question about where is the header of the `python` command in the `tempy3.py`.*

This is merely a header for python, and is not an 'answer' to a 'question'. You are simply entering python mode, and not requesting anything back. *However*, if you try:

```
proc.communicate('1+1')
```

*Then that should write `2` to the file tempy4.tmp, right?*

**No**. This is because `communicate()` can only get output from the Unix command line, not the python. e.g.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen('ls', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=outFile, stderr=outFile, shell=True)
proc.communicate('-l')
```

Outputs:

```
student@ubuntu:~/Desktop/Testing$ pg tempy4.tmp                                
dummy.py
dummy.pyc
pyrun.py
tempy1.tmp
tempy2.tmp
tempy3.tmp
tempy4.tmp
```

I ran your program as it is, and `tempy4.tmp` actually shows `Hi Earth` once, and has the same error which you have put. However, if you get rid of the second `communicate()` and have only one, you can do as @user590028 pointed out:

```
proc.communicate('import dummy\ndummy.hi()\n')
```

However, instead of having all the commands bunched into one line, subprocess allows you to do this with `stdin.write`:

```
proc.stdin.write('import dummy\n')
proc.communicate('dummy.hi()')
```

*Make sure you put `\n` after your command for a new line.
They both output:

```
Hi Earth
Hi Earth
```

Comment: 1. you can close `outFile` even before `.communicate()` is called -- immediately after `Popen()` (the subprocess has its own copy) 2. `.communicate()` waits for the subprocess to finish i.e., the child process has been reaped by the time `.communicate()` returns. 3. the explanation about `tempy3.py` header is incorrect. python doesn't print header in non-interactive mode (stdin is not a tty). `-i` option can force interactive mode.